# Writing bytes to an int in Kernel Mode using copy_from_user

Tags: c, kernel, driver

Good afternoon, I'm having an issue today where I'm creating a device driver, where I can get it to read the dice_read function perfectly, but when I try to use dice_write, it seems like it doesn't do anything at all. I've even added printk's to try to Troubleshoot and it seems like it never gets there anyways. not quite sure why. I'm just trying to use the line "echo -ne \x8\x4 > /dev/dice" and it's supposed to take the byte with "4" and put it in an int. I've added my dice_write below. Thanks! (sides is a global variable)

```
static ssize_t dice_write(struct file * file, const char * buf,
                      size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    char *data = kmalloc(sizeof(buf), GFP_KERNEL);

    copy_from_user(data, &buf, count);

    int i = sizeof(data);
    sides = 0;
    char digit = data[i - 1];
    if(digit >= '0' && digit <= '9'){
        sides = digit - '0';
    }

    kfree(data);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please check the value of `sizeof(buf)`, and check also the return of `kmalloc` if it's Null.

Comment: @TomKuschel When I used my echo command, nothing was returned. Is it an issue with the way I'm using echo?

Comment: which I meant is: (1) sizeof(buf) is always the size of the pointer of (const char *), probably 8 on your machine. Is that what you want?
(2) if data is NULL after kmalloc(), the sizeof(data) equals 0, and there is a problem also with data [i-1] a.s.o.
(3) I hope count is never > 8, because with copy_from_user() - we do not see this function - possibly you write into a data area outside that 8 byte buffer,,,, Please use a debugger for watching your variables!

Comment: **Too many problems** with the code. Aside listed in the above comment: 1. `buf` is by itself a pointer to the user data, so it should be passed to `copy_from_user`, not a `&buf`. 2. Value `sizeof(data)` same as `sizeof(buf)`, that is 8. 3. `copy_from_user` returns number of **remaining** bytes (which cannot be read), but value returned from `.write` function should reflect number of bytes which has been **written**.